# Spring controller getting bodyRequest null

Tags: spring-boot, controller

I am facing a problem while trying to process a POST request via POSTMAN.
In my controller I have :

```
@ApiOperation(value = "xxxx", notes = "xxxx", response = 
    String.class, authorizations = {
    @Authorization(value = "basicAuth")
}, tags={ "saveCourse", })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful operation", response = 
String.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not found", response = 
String.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Invalid input", response = 
String.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error", response = 
String.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "unexpected error", response = 
String.class) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/course/saveCourse",
    produces = { "application/json"}, 
    consumes = { "application/json"},
    method = RequestMethod.POST)   
ResponseEntity<String> saveCourse(@ApiParam(value = "xxxxx" ,required=true ) @RequestBody Course coure){
LOG.info(course.toString);
}
```

Class Course :

```
public class Course  implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@JsonProperty("prof")
private Prof prof = null;

@JsonProperty("students")
private List<Strudent> students = new ArrayList<Strudent>();

// getters & setters 
// ...
}
```

class Prof :

```
public class Prof  implements Serializable {
  @JsonProperty("profLastName")
  private String profLastName = null;

  @JsonProperty("profFirstName")
  private String profFirstName = null;

  @JsonProperty("age")
  private int age = null;

  // getters & setters
}
```

class Student :

```
public class Student  implements Serializable {
  @JsonProperty("studentId")
  private String studentId = null;

  @JsonProperty("studentName")
  private String studentName = null;

  @JsonProperty("studAge")
  private int studAge = null;

  // getters & setters
  // ...
}
```

in POSTMAN I am sending a POST request with the header :

```
Content-Type : application/json
```

the body :

```
{
    "prof": {
         "profLastName":"test",
         "profFirstName":"test",
         "age":"30"
    },
    "students" :[
    "{'studentId':'0','studentName':'','studAge':'00'}",
    "{'studentId':'2','studentName':'','studAge':'21'}",
    "{'studentId':'4','studentName':'','studAge':'40'}",
    "{'studentId':'6','studentName':'','studAge':'60'}"
    ]
}
```

When I process the request I am getting the RequestBody null :

> [http-nio-xxxx-exec-4] INFO com.test.myControllerIml - class Course {
>       prof: null
>       students: []
>   }

Comment: when I debug my request : 
    CharStreams.toString(request.getReader())

I am getting the json that I sent, so probably the issue is in the mapping.

N.B : we use Swagger to generate our API.

Answer (score 0):

you request body is wrong
you should use

```
{
    "prof": {
         "profLastName":"test",
         "profFirstName":"test",
         "age":"30"
    },
    "students" :[
    {"studentId":"0","studentName":"","studAge":"00"},
    {"studentId":"2","studentName":"","studAge":"21"},
    {"studentId":"4","studentName":"","studAge":"40"},
    {"studentId":"6","studentName":"","studAge":"60"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello Melad,
I tried your solution but had the same result.
Thank you

Comment: your code code works fine for me. i noticed some compilation errors and fixed it locally.